# Robolectric 3.0 java.lang.NoSuchMethodException on create activity

Tags: java, android, testing, robolectric

I was excited to hear that android studio had made some updates to make unit testing simple to do in android studio so I have been trying to set up roboelectric but I cant get past this error that occurs during the following method.

```
MainActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();
```

with the following stacktrace

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Object.attach(android.content.Context, android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.Instrumentation, android.os.IBinder, int, android.app.Application, android.content.Intent, android.content.pm.ActivityInfo, java.lang.CharSequence, android.app.Activity, java.lang.String, android.app.Activity$NonConfigurationInstances, android.content.res.Configuration)
>       at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.traverseClassHierarchy(ReflectionHelpers.java:248)
>       at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:138)
>       ... 36 more

Why this is occurring and what I can do to get past it?

Comment: Post all of your code.